# Duplicate Values using UNION

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query below  and I'm having trouble using UNION, it duplicates the `purok`.

```
SELECT h.cpurok as purok,
COUNT(m.cgender) AS total,
SUM(CASE WHEN m.cgender::text = 'Male'::text THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS male, 
SUM(CASE WHEN m.cgender::text = 'Female'::text THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS female
FROM tbl_member as m, tbl_household as h, tbl_barangay as b, tbl_answer as a
WHERE h.chholdnumber=m.chholdnumber 
and h.cbrgycode=b.cbrgycode 
and b.cbrgyname='AGAO' 
and a.nqid=16 
and a.nmemberid=m.nmemberid
and choice in ('29','30','31','32','35','36')
GROUP BY purok 
UNION
SELECT h.cpurok as purok,
0 AS total, 0 AS male, 0 AS female
FROM tbl_household as h, tbl_answer as a
WHERE a.nqid=15
and choice='21'
order by purok
```

The output is fine, just want to remove the duplicated `purok` which has `0` values in `total,male,female`.

[image: output of the query above]

The marked red on the image above should be removed.

Comment: Union makes rows, not individual keys, unique. In your case, you have two different rows - `01, 2, 2, 0` and `01, 0, 0, 0`, so `UNION` keeps both of them.

Comment: `JOIN` could work, but the `CASE` statement that you would need to make it work would get complicated. You could probably `UNION ALL` on the table level, wrap that in a big `GROUP BY` query on `purok`.

Comment: Would you mind answering it or giving some examples?

Comment: How does table `tbl_answer` joined to table `tbl_household` in your second query? There is no condition where `h.something` would be matched to `a.somethingElse`.

Comment: `tbl_member` and `tbl_answer` are the related by `nmemberid`.

Comment: That's in the first `SELECT`. How about the second one? There is no `nmemberid` in that query.

Comment: My bad, I thought that if you have used the condition in the first `SELECT`, it is not necessary to used it on the second when using `UNION`.

Comment: @SachiTekina SIDE NOTE : `VARCHAR` type for _column_ `purok` is a bad idea, consider `INT`

Answer (score 2):

Union makes rows, not individual keys, unique. In your case, you have two different rows - `01, 2, 2, 0` and `01, 0, 0, 0`, so `UNION` keeps both of them.

You could probably `UNION ALL` on the table level, wrap that in a big `GROUP BY` query on `purok`:

```
SELECT purok,
SUM(num) AS total,
SUM(male) AS male, 
SUM(female) AS female
FROM (

    SELECT
        h.cpurok AS
    ,   1 AS num
    ,   CASE WHEN m.cgender::text = 'Male'::text THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS male
    ,   CASE WHEN m.cgender::text = 'Female'::text THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS female
    FROM tbl_member as m
    JOIN tbl_household as h ON h.chholdnumber=m.chholdnumber
    JOIN tbl_barangay as b ON h.cbrgycode=b.cbrgycode AND b.cbrgyname='AGAO'
    JOIN tbl_answer as a ON a.nmemberid=m.nmemberid AND a.nqid=16
    WHERE choice in ('29','30','31','32','35','36')

    UNION ALL

    SELECT h.cpurok as purok,
    0 AS num, 0 AS male, 0 AS female
    FROM tbl_household as h
    JOIN tbl_answer as a ON h.householdid=a.householdid AND a.nqid=15
    WHERE choice='21'
) raw
GROUP BY purok 
ORDER BY purok
```

Note: your query does not join `tbl_household` to `tbl_answer`, so I "invented" a placeholder join condition `h.householdid=a.householdid`. You need to replace it with an actual join criterion.